# Why ShopifyPOS.fetchCart dose not working?

Tags: javascript, shopify

as per doc from shopify this should work but not sure what it is not working with me.

below is my code snipit.

```js
    ShopifyPOS.ready(function(){
      console.log('Start of ShopifyPOS.ready');
      ShopifyPOS.fetchCart({
        success: function(cart) {
          console.log('success');
            // read the cart or call any cart functions here
            // e.g. cart.line_items or cart.addLineItem(...)
        },
        error: function(errors) {
            //ShopifyPOS.flashError("Failed to retrieve cart")
            console.log('errors');
        }
      });
        console.log('End of ShopifyPOS.ready');
    });
```

here is my console output :

[check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmNNB.png)
as shown in console output seems ShopifyPOS.ready is not getting called!

Comment: From the console.log messages, it seems like `ShopifyPOS.ready` is being called. The [docs mention](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/embedded-apps/shopify-pos-app-sdk/methods#cart-fetch) that `.fetchCart` is "Only available in the Edit Cart integration". Is that the integration you're using with this code?

Comment: @thmsdnnr , i'm not sure is it required to specify integration type somewhere?